Cannot get VOSK docker image to run
I am trying to setup a VOSK websocket server. I am running Debian 12 and installed VOSK according to the instructions and it works using the cli commands. No issues. I know nothing about docker, and the only instructions I can find to run the websocket is using docker. I installed docker according to the instructions for Debian 12 and no errors. I ran the docker command as specifed -
docker run -d -p 2700:2700 alphacep/kaldi-vosk-server
Nothing. When I run
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: audio/wav" --data-binary ./busy.wav "http://localhost:2700/client/ws/speech"
I get a
Failed to connect to localhost port 2700 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
netstat does not show port 2700 open and figured out how to see the docker containers
 docker ps -a CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                        COMMAND   CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES 80d57b92b88b   alphacep/kaldi-vosk-server   "bash"    7 seconds ago   Exited (0) 6 seconds ago             ecstatic_carson
so it is exiting. I cannot find any logs or error codes. If I run a 'docker logs 80d57b92b88b" I get no lines at all. If I run -
docker run -it -p 2700:2700 alphacep/kaldi-vosk-server
I get the console, but nothing after that. I now have port 2700 open in netstat and if I run the curl command I get -
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
but no errors still, no logs, no output. As I mentined this is the first time I have ever used docker so I have been just looking up commands to try to figure this out. Any suggestions? Thansks!
